# Angularjs ng-csv export excel with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, csv

I'm trying to export my table to an excel file, I'm searching examples like this:

[Example ng-csv](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18208/)

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-csv="testDelim" csv-header="['Field A', 'Field B', 'Field C']" csv-column-order="order" filename="custom.csv">Download CSV</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
angular
.module('myApp',['ngSanitize', 'ngCsv'])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.order = [ 'b', 'a', 'c' ];
    $scope.testDelim = [ {a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6} ];
});
```

But this and all examples only make one column when export the Excel, like this:

[image: Result]

And I want:

[image: Expected]

Is any form to separate the colums on the Excel? Or other tool to export .csv in Angularjs.

Comment: it works properly in this demo https://codepen.io/sachila/pen/veYYxm

Comment: I get the same result :(

Comment: maybe this might help https://nimbleschedule.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202708373-Why-is-excel-showing-the-schedule-export-in-one-column-

Comment: omg, I thought it was the fault of the code, and it was from microsoft excel ... thanks!

Comment: yeah no problem :D